# How to get WordPress post as a whole HTML page from PHP manually?

Tags: wordpress

I try to export WordPress posts as HTML by PHP manually.

I can get only title, content, excerpt,...

I expect to export a whole post page the same as what I view the post page in website.
How can I get HTML of the post page?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to retrieve the HTML you mean the content of a post

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

You can also use: 
`get_the_content( string $more_link_text = null, bool $strip_teaser = false, WP_Post|object|int $post = null )`
 this is the fuction of wordpress.org
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: Thank for your answer. Actually I want a whole page of post detail.